# Copying data into Range name in excel 2007 via vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

If I populate an object in vba with 10 values, and paste it into a range that has been defined to be 200 rows long, will these 10 values be copied over and over again in the predefined range?

note: the populating and pasting is done via vba code, and the range is defined in excel.

this seems to be happening in excel vba 2007, but not in 2010. need to fix the 2007 problem. would appreciate your input..

thanks in adv!

Comment: Seeing your code would be useful. Else we can only guess.

Comment: How can you accept an answer when you haven't fully laid out your problem?

Comment: the full problem is intricate, hence i laid out an abstraction of it. the answer gives me, and any user who faces a similar situation, what we need to solve it.

Comment: Roy, thanks for the response. My concern was/is that there may not be enough detail in your question to help someone else. Especially for code that works in one xl version but not another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid pasting extra data, `Set` a variable to your named range and `Resize` that variable before pasting, eg

If the 'object' being pasted is a `Range`

```
Set rng = [MyNamedRange]
rng.Resize(CopyFormRange.Rows.Count, CopyFormRange.Columns.Count).Copy CopyFormRange
```

If the 'object' being pasted is an Array

```
Set rng = [MyNamedRange]
rng.Resize(UBound(CopyFromArray, 1) - LBound(CopyFromArray, 1), _
           UBound(CopyFromArray, 2) - LBound(CopyFromArray, 2)).Copy CopyFormRange
```